# SQL Server CE 4.0 addin not working with VS2013

Tags: wpf, sql-server-ce

Need help for adding SQL Server CE database to WPF desktop application. I am using VS 2013 professional preview.

I've tried installing the SQL Server CE toolbox add-in, but that toolbox is not allowing me to add SQL Server CE 4.0 connection. I am not allowed to post the image being a less reputed guy, else I would have shown the snippet of VS. Is the toolbox not supported in VS 2013 ?

Also just wanted to know, using SQL Server CE would be a good idea to use as a database for desktop application assuming that my database may have around 10million rows (max.)

Comment: Also the toolbox shows runtime 3.5 not found

Comment: for now you have to install sql ce 3.5 for the toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server Compact Toolbox works with and is fully supported with Visual Studio 2013, but it requires either the 3.5 SP2 or 4.0 SQL Server Compact runtime to be installed. See this for more info and download links: https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/documentation (I am the author of the Toolbox)

Comment: Do i have to write sql query for creating a table. No option or shortcut for directly creating a table?

Comment: Release 3.6, currently in alpha, has a Table Builder https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/108998 - is it something like that you are after?

Comment: But accessing sqlce in your project, and using the model editor etc- for me doesn't work in 2013, so there's really no point.

Pretty major breaking change ol MS pulled on us there.

Comment: Feel free to request specific feature requests to the Toolbox at the Codplex issue tracker